# Warnings while using NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, iphone, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

As i am new to AutoLayout Constraints i am facing some warnings related to tableview cell content view as i added some UI elements using constraints. And the warnings which i found in console is

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Can Any one explain me the warning and solution?

Comment: warning is

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85dbe84490 H:[UIView:0x7f85dbe842d0(329)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85dbe84f00 H:[UIView:0x7f85dbe842d0]-(1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85dbe6a780 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85dbe84f50 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f85dbe842d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85dbe6a780 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85dbe95c70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85dbe6a780(414)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85dbe84490 H:[UIView:0x7f85dbe842d0(329)]>

Comment: you must have not set the constraint properly in view

Comment: Ya, i consist of lot of UI elements. More over can you explain me the warning which i posted as comment ??

Comment: you have to set the constraints as per the requiremnt

Comment: The warning simply means that one or more constraints cannot be satisfied at the same time. From the looks of it, this is a height issue - the height of the components together don't satisfy the overall height constraints

Comment: I could help you if you could share the screen shot of your desired cell design.

Comment: It's hard to read constraints from these VFL's, seem like you have set fixed width to you'r view which has leading and trailing space.

Comment: Its warning tells to you, that while View rendered on screen of your device(physical or simulator), occured an conflict between some constraints.
And Autolayout break(disable some constraints) with purpose, that your view maximatelly look like you want.
You need recheck all constraints, for finding conflicts.
Or provide additional properties to your constraints like `compression` `hugging`

Answer (score 0):

Posting useful links.

*Apple's detailed guide how to understand, debug and fix autolayout warnings.*

[Auto Layout Guide: Debugging Tricks and Tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html)

*Tool to visualize conflicting constraints.*

[WTF Auto Layout](https://www.wtfautolayout.com)